# Who put the key in the box, and how did they get it?

Tags: plot-explanation, stoker

In [Stoker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoker_(film)) the protagonist receives a pair of shoes every year for her birthday. She always believed them to be from her Dad. But the last birthday the dad is dead yet the box comes. The box has a key this time. The key opens the dad's desk drawer with materials explaining the family past that was a mystery before.

Logically, there are only three people who could have given her the key:

- **Dad** - arranged for the box and the key before he died, but as we can see from the moive he did not anticipate that he would die, and also the protagonist clearly says : [image] which implies that it was not her Dad after all. Also the Mrs. McGarrick indicates that she *is familiar* with the contents of the box.
- **Mrs. McGarrick** - but how could she get hold of the key to Dad's drawer with family secrets? She does not strike as thieving type.
- **Uncle Charlie** - that, given the plot, would be the most logical, but again, how would he get hold of the key?

So, who put the key in the box, and where did they get it from in the first place?